# postcss.config with import instead of require

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, postcss

I have the following `postcss.config.js`

```
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss("tailwind.config.js"),
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('autoprefixer') : null,
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? cssnano({ preset: 'default' })
      : null,
    require('postcss-discard-comments')(),
    require('postcss-discard-empty')(),
    purgecss({
      content: ['./dev/**/*.html', './src/**/*.ts'],
      defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
    })
  ]
}
```

I am trying to covert this to use `import` instead since it is a `ES6` module I am creating.

I tried the following:

```
const purgecss = import('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');
const cssnano = import('cssnano');
const tailwindcss = import('tailwindcss');
const autoprefixer = import('autoprefixer');
const discardComments = import('postcss-discard-comments');
const discardEmpty = import('postcss-discard-empty');
module.
  exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss,
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? autoprefixer : null,
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? cssnano({preset: 'default'})
      : null,
    discardComments,
    discardEmpty,
    purgecss({
      content: ['./dev/**/*.html', './src/**/*.ts'],
      defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
    }),
  ],
};
```

And then changed the filename to `cjs` and my `tailwind.config` to end in the same, however I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: purgecss is not a function
```

I tried removing purge to see if it works, but it just gives me another error:

```
TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found at: plugins[0]
```

How can I correctly change to use `import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` is a keyword not a function so it has a different syntax. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

So, for example

```
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');
```

becomes

```
import purgecss from '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss';
```

Comment: To be fair, as the documentation shows, `import` is also a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports